# How do I create an ordered list using angular?

Tags: angular, arraylist, html-lists, ngfor

Usually creating an ordered list is pretty simple but I am trying to do it in angular while using the *ngFor directive. The following code works like a charm except for the fact that it just says the number 1 next to each ordered list item in my resulting array instead of numbering them sequentially. I would like to make sure each item is numbered correctly ie( 1 2 3 4 etc..  instead of 1 1 1 1). How can I achieve this?

`<div *ngFor="let item of result; let i=index">
  <ol>
    <li *ngIf="i<3"> {{item.key}} appears {{item.value}} {{(item.value>1)? 'times' : 'time'}}
      </li>
      </ol>
</div>

//currently outputs 
1.bacon appears 3 times
1.pepperoni appears 3 times
1.beef appears 2 times`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're looping around the root `<div>` so you're actually generating 3 `<ol>` instead of 3 `<li>` inside one `<ol>`. You need to loop around `<li>` but since you cannot have `ngFor` and `ngIf` on the same element you need to use `<ng-container>`. Something like this:

```
<div >
  <ol>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of result; let i=index">
      <li *ngIf="i < 3">{{item.key}} appears {{item.value}} {{(item.value>1)? 'times' : 'time'}}</li>
   </ng-container>    
  </ol>
</div>
```